# Schedule to Overwrite existing directory powershell

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell, trying to achieve the following:

Run the command below, for every 5 minutes (Folder updates,overwrite files) for 1 hour, every day.

Schedule Task:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument 'C:\Users\test.ps1' 

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 8:00am

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "test" -Description "test description"
```

After a  X amount of time, folder gets compressed

Zip command:

```
Compress-Archive -Path "$folder\*.txt\" -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath $folder\ZIPFILE
```

Not being able to overwrite the current directory with same destination/same name

```
 Copy-Item "C:\Users\$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")\*" "C:\Users\" -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: The folder is already there, so why are you trying to copy it?

Comment: folder is there, but what if new files start to come in, and the folder is already zipped. So during 1 hour block, scripts will run every 5 minutes, until all the files are in " and then zip it